# Jasper Reports - Fetch detail object details from BaseColumn class in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a jasper report using java but i am not sure how do i fetch details of the cells which are inside my columns.

in the below screenshot i want the highlighted JRDesignFrame Object values. But i am not able to get it.

[image].

I am trying to iterate the list

```
for (BaseColumn col : list)
{
}
```

When i do a `col.getDetail` there is no option as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `BaseColumn` reference to `net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.Column`, which has a `getDetailCell` method.

So you'll have something like this:

```
for (BaseColumn col : list)
{
    if (col instanceof Column)
    {
        Cell detailCell = ((Column) col).getDetailCell();
        JRDesignFrame frame = (JRDesignFrame) detailCell.getElements()[0];
        ...
    }
}
```